# Exploring the [restricted-areas] of our tag space

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [restricted-areas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-areas) (currently three questions, no tag wiki) is a mess.

In theory, the phrase brings to mind places such as military bases and nature preserves that often require special permits to enter above and beyond permission to enter or remain in the country in which they are situated. For example, someone lawfully in the USA may not be allowed to enter the Pentagon or Area 51 without a pass issued by the US military. However, only one of the questions in this tag actually relates to this concept - the others are about health-related travel restrictions between jurisdictions.

Do we need this tag at all?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right that [travel-restrictions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel-restrictions) should have a tag separate to [restricted-areas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restricted-areas) but and both are probably perfectly valid tags. I am very surprised that there is only one question on restricted areas at present - I would have expected not only ones referring to military bases, firing ranges etc., but also seasonal restrictions in some national parks and so on.